# UWP - ListView Issue, I can't add my search to the list

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have to use a list.

I'm trying to add my searched data to the view list
and it's crashing again and again.

i thing the issue is in list view
Thank you.

Error:

> System.Exception: 'Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))'

XML:

```
        <ListView  x:Name="listView" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Grid.RowSpan="5" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="421" Width="711" Margin="0,93,0,0" Grid.Column="1">
        <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Padding="12" Background="{ThemeResource SystemBaseLowColor}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Name" Style="{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Publisher" Style="{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="PublishDate" Style="{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="Quantity" Style="{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Text="Category" Style="{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" Text="Price" Style="{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Name="TableDataTemplate">
                <Grid Height="48" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Name}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="nameTbx" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding model.Publisher}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding model.PublishDate}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding model.Quantity}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding model.Category}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="6" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding model.Price}"/>

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

c#:

```
 {
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();


        listView.ItemsSource = BookLib.ItemCollection.Items;   


    }


    private void searchTbx_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var match = BookLib.ItemCollection.Items.Find(x => x.Name.ToLower() == searchTbx.Text.ToLower());
        if (match != null)
        {
            listView.Items.Add(match.Name);
        }
    }
```

please help me to slove this issue

Answer (score 2):

You set the `ItemsSource` to `BookLib.ItemCollection.Items` in the constructor, means that, all the elements of `BookLib.ItemCollection.Items` are now items of that `listView`.

So, in the TextChanged event, aren't you trying to add the same Item which is already in the `listView`?

That's why your app is crashing.

**Solution:**
Remove this line from the constructor:

```
listView.ItemsSource = BookLib.ItemCollection.Items;
```

You didn't mention the ViewModel you are using for the `listview`. I am assuming It's like this:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Publisher { get; set; }
    ………
    ………
    ………
}
```

Then you should mention the Data type in the `ItemTemplate` of your `listView` like this:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="TableDataTemplate" x:DataType="Book">
            <Grid …………
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

this should solve your problem.

**Note:**
If you want to let the user search through the `BookLib.ItemCollection.Items`, consider using an [AutoSuggestBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.AutoSuggestBox).

Comment: Tnx a lot, at the BookLib.ItemCollection.Items i have: private static List<AbstractItem> _items = _items = new List<AbstractItem>(); , It's holding all the items that the user have to search through

Comment: yeah, and you want to let user search in this `BookLib.ItemCollection.Items` , right?

Comment: Yeah -> it's a list

Comment: You should do that with `AutoSuggestBox`. Look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/auto-suggest-box